# Value categories: Why does en.cppreference.com differentiate between an object and a bit-field?

Tags: c++

From [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) documentation.

> - a prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an expression whose evaluation either
>
>   - computes the value of the operand of an operator or is a void expression (such prvalue has no result object), or
>   - initializes an object or a bit-field (such prvalue is said to have a result object). With the exception of decltype, all class and array prvalues have a result object even if it is discarded. The result object may be a variable, an object created by new-expression, a temporary created by temporary materialization, or a member thereof;

A bit field is an object with fixed width in bits. (From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).)

However it would seem to me, given the context of the above, that the word "bit-field" should be interpreted as any data stored in memory, such as a trivial type (int, double, etc), an array or a struct.

In other words I do not understand why en.cppreference.com explicitly differentiate between "object" and "bit-field".

If "bit-field" is intended to be interpreted as *literally* `identifier(optional) attr(optional) : size` then since any fundamental type is also a bit field, why was the word "bit-field" used here instead of "object" or "fundamental/trivial data type".

Reason for asking is I have read this page before many times but always found the use of the word "bit-field" confusing. Not because I didn't know what a bit field was, but because I didn't understand the significance of the use of the phrase here.

Comment: *"A bit field is an object"* Not from [object's definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). `sizeof (bitfield)` is wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42 What is different about the behaviour of `sizeof`?

Comment: Hmm. I found this in the C++17 Draft Standard: *Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, ...*

Comment: It's not clear to me that bit fields are not objects according to the standard. "there are no pointers to bit-fields" ([source](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit#3)) is an important distinction. But other parts in the standard like what @AdrianMole quoted seem to indirectly imply that bit fields are objects:  "Unless it is a bit-field, an object with nonzero size [...]" ([source](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-8.4))

Comment: "A bit field is an object with fixed width in bits" is possibly too general, because not all objects with fixed bit widths are bit fields (every type has a fixed size in bytes, and thus a fixed size in bits). A bit field is only a bit field if it is explicitly declared as one. If you can take its address, it's not a bit field.

Comment: About `sizeof`: "The sizeof operator shall not be applied to [...] a glvalue that designates a bit-field" ([source](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1)

Comment: Between the standard, the way cppreference try to digest it to make it clear, the fact that C++ is complicated with lot of corner case (as bitfield)...

Comment: @alterigel Seems kind of arbitrary to have an exception for bitfield types. Why shouldn't I be able to take the address of one? The bitfield must have some address in memory, surely? Is there a gramatical reason why this is forbidden?

Comment: Object addresses in C++ are always in bytes. A bit field does not necessarily align to byte boundaries, and there's no way to capture this using an address. How would you take the address of the 3rd bit in a `char` object?

Comment: @alterigel One would not take the address of the 3rd bit but the address operator (I propose) should return the lowest memory address which still contains (part of) the object. Why would this not be desirable?

Comment: It would be presumably aligned to a 4 byte boundary but this is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant how would you uniquely obtain the address to the member `x.c` in `struct { int a : 1, b : 1, c : 1, d : 1; } x;` such that it doesn't silently alias or overlap with other members? Its byte address is simply not useful if it's ambiguous with other bit fields and if one needs additional information (e.g. the bit length and bit offset) to meaningfully read and write that member.

Comment: @alterigel I see your point. I was supposing the returned address would be the same value for all of those.